# How do I catch metasploit session scripts error code in ruby?

Tags: metasploit, ruby

I was able to start a session using metasploit framework (msf6) with an android but after a while being in the session, the meterpreter session closes. Luckily however after a few seconds, another stage payload gets sent out, giving me access to another meterpreter session. I could login AGAIN using `sessions <id>`

I'm trying to run a session script using the `run` command and I want to catch this error:

```
[-] Error running command print_status: Rex::TimeoutError Operation timed out.
```

when my meterpreter sessions get closed to automatically open a new session again using `sessions <id>`.

For example, I am running this ruby script in the session, but general Ruby syntax error catching doesn't work.

```
<ruby>
begin
  while true
    print_status("Hello world")
  end
rescue => e
  print_status("This is where I want to catch when my session gets closed")
  print_status("The print_status doesn't work once meterpreter prompt closes")
end
</ruby>
```

Is it normal for meterpreter sessions to timeout after a while? Because I've learned to live with it, but it would be nice if I don't have to keep typing in `sessions <new id>` to get a new session after every session use.

Comment: This is mostly looking like a Ruby programming question, not a security question. I would clean up the tangential comments, add in what you've tried and what the results were and move this to StackOverflow.

Comment: @schroeder thats what i thought at first but it cant be pertinent to just ruby itself but some code in the metasploit framework itself.

Comment: Also there is nothing else i can think of trying as i have documented in my question a code sample i used to catch the error if the meterpreter session closes. I dont know but can I also post this to regular StackOverflow incase no one here knows what to do?